# Sealing OSB subfloor from moisture? Patching small gouges?

Tags: wood, floor, woodworking, subfloor, plywood

What are some methods that can be used to seal an OSB subfloor from moisture? And patch small gouges (quarter sized)?

Background:  Small Bathroom remodel.  Tile came up with finger pressure, underneath was Gypsum Concrete (Gyp-Crete or Pyrofill).  It was crumbled, mildewed and in loose chunks two foot around the tub, and a foot around toilet and vanity.  Removed it all to the door threshold to set new tiles.  OSB is in great shape, but there is a tiny bit of mildew on the surface in a few spots and some small gouges where the Gyp-Crete took up a quarter-sized strand.  Will either go with HardieBacker 500 or self-leveling concrete to raise floor up to height to tile.  To remove the mildew, I've done light sanding and sprayed bleach solution and spread it with a rag.  I plan to fill the gouges with epoxy (unless there is a cheaper recommendation. Epoxy is a bit on the pricey side).  I'd like to moisture seal the OSB also since moisture has found it's way down there in the past.

Edit:  Decided to go with Durham's Water Putty.  $2 for 1 lb. of powder that never dries out.  Least expensive option I could find.

**Safety Note:**  Gypsum Concrete contains silica which can cause silicosis.  If you're going to remove it use a respirator, the type with the rubber face seal and replaceable >= N95 cartridges.  Spray bottle water all over the Gyp-Crete before removing it. Don't cut with a saw or hammer it all out.  Take a painter's tool with a hammer butt or a chisel, and chisel all around the edges of the room, and the pieces will lift out and pry up.  Hammering the Gyp-Crete makes lots of dust, and may make fracture lines a few feet long.  Possibly where you don't want it broken.  When it's all out, spray more water and use a wet rag to clean up the dust/debris.  Sweeping or vacuuming with a shop-vac will put all the dust in the air == bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stop moisture from getting to the subfloor then a membrane under your tile would be better than sealing the OSB. Better to stop it **before** it gets there than trying to seal the wood.

Tile and grout are **not** waterproof and if exposed to water regularly the water will work its way into the sub-flooring.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a membrane material.  Thanks!

Comment: There are some favorites of tile installers: Kerdi, Trugard, and Laticrete makes one that just has a number 9235.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-fill the gouges if you prefer & I would just go with a wood putty for that. Sealing the OSB can be a few coats of polyurethane or primer & paint, **ONLY IF** you aren't going to be required or suggested to use a Bonding Agent for self-leveling cement or thin-set. A Bonding Agent will also provide some decent sealing & moisture protection.

Layers of Cement Backer Board screwed & glued to the OSB with thin-set (or whatever you prefer or may be suggested) & to each other with alternating seams also with thin-set (?) will be your strongest & quietest floor...outside of getting rid of the OSB garbage & replacing it with actual plywood of thicker grade, which is slightly to strongly recommended by most manufacturers.

Comment: I found Durham's Water Putty to be the least expensive option @ $2 per pound.  Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Comment: That should work great & I'm sure you'll do a great job with everything. You have the right concerns & don't shy away from trying to be a perfectionist, "pro's" are very shy of that.